# Custom angular search filter order by number of words matching

Tags: angularjs, search, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I want to create a predictive text custom filter in angular JS that filters out an array of strings based on search query and order them by the number of words matching with the words in the search query.

The filter should return the same and all the records even if the order of the words in the search query dosn't matches with the order they appear in the records array.(For example if I search for "table cloth" as a search query it should be able to match against "Decorative cloth for table" also (Note that angular filter dosen't do this))

Also only prefix matches for words inside the search query should be allowed(for example if I have a record containing a word "phone", if I type "one" some where in the search query it should not shown).

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom filter myself that does the following things

1. Prefix word match only.
2. Random word index matching.
3. Sorting based on number of words matched.

Here's the code

HTML

```
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat = "helpFAQ in helpCtrl.helpFAQs | filter: helpCtrl.filterBySearch | orderBy: ['-matchCount','priority'] | limitTo : helpCtrl.helpFaqLimit track by $index " ><a title="">{{helpFAQ.question}}</a></li>
                <li ng-if ="helpCtrl.showLessFaq"><a ng-click = "helpCtrl.showMoreFaq()" title="helpCtrl">[...]</a></li>
            </ul>
```

AngularJS custom filter

```
 vm.helpFAQs = [{"question":"How can i hide an site?",
                 "priority":1},
                {"question":"How can i stop an ad?",
                "priority":7},
                {"question":"How do i change my email address?",
                "priority":9},
                {"question":"How do i pay electricity bill?",
                "priority":3},
                {"question":"How do i see the number of times I logged in?",
                "priority":6},
                {"question":"How do i set up a new connection?",
                "priority":3},
                {"question":"Where can i see disclosures for my account?",
                "priority":1},
                {"question":"Where can i see my privacy setting?",
                "priority":4},
                {"question":"Why can't i see my profile?",
                "priority":2}
                ];
vm.serchBoxKeyed = function(searchTerm){
     vm.regex = new RegExp('\\b' + vm.escapeRegExp(searchTerm), 'i');
}

vm.filterBySearch = function(topic) {
    topic.matchCount = 0;
    var searchTextSplit = vm.searchQuery.toLowerCase().split(' ');
      for(var y = 0; y < searchTextSplit.length; y++){
        vm.serchBoxKeyed(searchTextSplit[y]);
        var prefixMatch =vm.regex.test(topic.question);
        if(topic.question.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTextSplit[y]) !== -1 && prefixMatch){
          topic.matchCount = topic.matchCount + 1;
        }
      }     
      if(topic.matchCount>0)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
};


vm.escapeRegExp = function(searchTerm){
  return searchTerm.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```